Is there a way to make dynamical representations of a visual type within emacs without the use of xwidgets?
I have been reading the emacs lisp introduction and emacs lisp manual. In the elisp introduction the author says that one should think of emacs as a "extensible computing environment" as opposed to a "extensible text editor". This is a very nice idea, but one that seems a little bit too idealistic to be the truth.
I wanted to create a graph visualization program that worked within emacs (using elisp if possible and sufficiently performant to run), my interest is in making navigating org-roam files more pleasant, like what is possible in the Obsidian program. There is a emacs "solution" for this in the form of https://github.com/org-roam/org-roam-ui (org-roam-ui), but altough it has some quite nice features, I dislike this "solution" because it involves using the rendering utilities of a web browser to make this work, and so it becomes necessary to have emacs and a browser open at the same time to make this work, that is, it is very badly integrated.
One way I believe I could get around this is if I compiled emacs with GTK+ WebKit and used a xwidgets browser to open the web ui of org-roam-ui within it to make everything be inside emacs, but this seems quite clunky.
Using the graphical capabilities of GTK+ WebKit in emacs it seems reasonable to think that I could write a graphical xwidget specifically for displaying in a dynamical way a graph visualizer (since people even wrote somewhat of a web browser inside emacs using it), but is there a way to do it without xwidgets specifically? Any other graphical library within emacs is OK for me.
Also, is there a way to code graphics using elisp in the same way one might program text functions, but where instead of the character as the fundamental building blocks, one has pixels? Could this make a representation of a graphical imager be accessible trough terminals where images could be broken down to pixelated versions?

https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Please post a single, succinct, preferably concrete question per post.

I could argue that my question IS about the capabilities of elisp with respect to graphical programming in comparison, for example, with the capabilities of javascript in a browser to allow graphical programming. I have not asked how to program any specific application, although I have explained my motivation for asking about graphical applications using elisp, neither have I talked about snippets of code. It is "about the nature of the language itself"!

Your question is not really answerable, but I’ll give you some background information. Emacs buffers can already display graphics. These can be raster graphics in several formats (such as gif, jpeg, or png) or they can be svg for vector graphics. Each graphic is treated like a character, even if this results in a “line” of text that is taller than the whole window the buffer is displayed in. You can certainly build a UI or a graph visualizer out of multiple graphics, arranging them in a buffer to achieve the look you want.
Emacs currently has no facility for displaying graphics in a terminal environment, although several protocols exist whereby a program running in a terminal can request graphics to be displayed. These include Sixels (raster graphics), ReGIS (vector graphics), the apparently unnamed protocol used by Tektronix terminals such as the 4010, the modern reinvention used by the Kitty terminal, and others. In principle you could add support for any or all of these protocols to Emacs, but it would be a pretty big job so nobody has done it yet.
Otherwise the xwidget protocol is your best bet. As you’ve discovered, you don’t need to use a web browser; you can write your own widget that displays whatever you need.

Is this scheme of buffering and then displaying several images ahead of time how that tetris application is implemented in emacs? Because it not only generates a "video" of the pieces falling, but a responsive application where the inputs of the user are used to update the graphical representation dynamically.

Probably! I have never actually looked. It could be a good source of implementation ideas.
